# Neo4j removing direction to relationship significantly takes more time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 queries which take significantly different amount of time. What dont I understand in relationships in Cypher to have this issue

less than 1 second with 5 results:

```
allshortestpaths((et)-[*]->(st))
```

less than 1 second with 3 results:

```
allshortestpaths((et)<-[*]-(st))
```

Takes forever (timeout):

```
allshortestpaths((et)-[*]-(st))
```

Why does this take forever. I would assume that this just has to return 8 results!!

Complete sample query:

```
profile match (s:Stop)--(st:Stoptime),     
              (e:Stop)--(et:Stoptime)  
              where s.name IN [ 'Schlump', 'U Schlump']     
              and e.name IN [ 'Hamburg Hbf', 'Hauptbahnhof Nord']         
              match p = allshortestpaths((et)-[*]->(st))      
              return p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `allshortestpaths((et)-[*]->(st))` you will have a paths that look like that : `(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)`

With `allshortestpaths((et)<-[*]-(st))` you will have a path that look like that : `(a)<--(b)<--(c)<--(d)`

With `allshortestpaths((et)<-[*]-(st))` you will have a paths that look like that :

- `(a)-->(b)-->(c)-->(d)`
- `(a)<--(b)<--(c)<--(d)`
- `(a)-->(b)<--(c)-->(d)`
- `(a)<--(b)<--(c)-->(d)`
- `(a)-->(b)-->(c)<--(d)`
- `(a)-->(b)<--(c)--<(d)`

Do you the differences ? The last one is a more complexe query than the previous ones, that's why it can take a long time, specially when you not specify the relationship type and the max depth of the path.

So here it'spossible that you are asking to Neo4j to traverse all your database ...